# How to implement inherited models in ActiveJDBC with associations between superclass and another model?

Tags: java, inheritance, activejdbc

I'd like to build something like this:

```
abstract class Owner extends Model {}
class User extends Owner {}
class Group extends Owner {}
class Thing extends Model {}
```

where every `Thing` has one and only one `Owner` that can be a `Group` OR an `User`.
How is it possible? Do I have to make Owner not abstract to let ActiveJDBC map the owner_id-column in the things-table to an owner? But how does it determine what kind of owner we have as http://javalite.io/inheritance says single table inheritance is not implemented in ActiceJDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Polymorphic Associations](http://javalite.io/polymorphic_associations). There is a difference between inheritance and ownership.

ActiveJDBC inheritance is limited to passing common functionality to sub-classes. Then you need to use relationships to create "A has many B" and the like, and [Polymorphic Associations](http://javalite.io/polymorphic_associations) seems like your best bet.

So, in your case User and Group will be polymorphic parents of Thing. It is your choice then to create a separate class Owner (only if they share some functionality).

So.. you will have three tables: USERS, GROUPS, THINGS.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The disadvantage of this solution is that a Thing can have a Group _and_ an User as Parents instead of having a unique Owner. Maybe it can be handled by validations - I haven't stepped in ActiveJDBC's validations yet. But the advantage is that it should work :-) I will give it a try.

Comment: It seems very slowly I' getting it: Thig can NOT have both parents as the special colums prevent that. There's only one parent id an the type for it in the table. Great!

Comment: It is working like a charm now. I created the class Owner because I do not always know what type it is exactly. Thing therefore has this method: public Owner getOwner() {
        if (this.getString("PARENT_TYPE").endsWith("Group")) {
            return this.parent(Group.class);
        }
        return this.parent(User.class);
    }

Comment: Exactly right,  this is why it is called a plymorphic relationship.